# Node.js send password though POST safely

Tags: node.js

If I have an SSL layer implemented to use HTTPS, I know I'm safe with sending the password via a JSON form and POST, but I have a number of projects that don't have an SSL certificate, and I still want to be able to send passwords securely.

If I use node-webkit to use node packages directly from the web page and use bcrypt-node to hash password strings and send it to a server, which will hash it one more time before comparing, would that at least prevent password theft via intercepting HTTP requests?

Because even if an attacker intercepts the HTTP request and got the password string that is hashed once, if I can assume that all login attempts have to be done through the website, then at least that intercepted string would be no use, since the server will hash it again before comparing.

I don't intend this to be a complete alternative to HTTPS in any way, but for this situation with the current assumptions, would this be safe enough? Are there any holes in my logic?

Example)

Lets say the original password is: 12345

And say the client hashes this into: 12345 -> abcde, and send to server.

Then the server would hash this into: abcde -> vwxyz.

Now, the attacker knows "abcde". But isn't that useless because even if the attacker enters this string into the password form,

the client will hash this into: abcde -> xxxxx (something else)

and the server will hash this into: xxxxx -> yyyyy (something else),

which is not equivalent to "vwxyz".

Answer (score 0):

What you described is not secure. Although hashing the password on the client prevents the original password from being discovered, an attacker would also be able to log in using that hash, so it's just as good as knowing the password.

Comment: Lets say the original password is: 12345
And say the client hashes this into: 12345 -> abcde, and send to server.
Then the server would hash this into: abcde -> vwxyz.

Now, the attacker knows "abcde". But isn't that useless because even if the attacker enters this string into the password form,
the client will hash this into: abcde -> xxxxx (something else)
and the server will hash this into: xxxxx -> yyyyy (something else),
which is not equivalent to "vwxyz".

Comment: Don't assume the attacker is going to be using your form.  They can POST the hashed value directly to your server, and your server would log them in.

Comment: Then is there virtually no way to secure password transfers without HTTPS?

Comment: You could use a key exchange to secure the password, but someone snooping your network traffic would be able to steal the session key when the server returns it, so the security would still fail.